# Can I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 to make a GUI for a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2012

I have made a rather cool utility for tabletop gaming using a batch file. However it's a batch file and thus rather irritating to read and input commands via the keyboard. I managed to pick up a copy of MS Visual Studio 2012 and noticed it has a mode for writing command prompt programs (aka batch/DOS). Can I use this to import my finished batch file and make a GUI for it? If so how?

Comment: No. You can either rewrite your batch file in C# or VB (which would be a very good idea), or make a GUI that launches the batch file.

Comment: What do you want the GUI to provide for your batch file.  Parameters?